# Haskell cabal repl - error: Variable not in scope: main

Tags: haskell, cabal, read-eval-print-loop, ghci

Issue can be reproduced by running `cabal repl` for [Haskell Editor Setup project](https://github.com/fairy-tale-agi-solutions/haskell-editor-setup/tree/faa16eef364d82a886b69d130c2cac9c84a5bbbe). Build instructions are [here](https://github.com/fairy-tale-agi-solutions/haskell-editor-setup/blob/faa16eef364d82a886b69d130c2cac9c84a5bbbe/CONTRIBUTING.md). After `cabal repl` loaded evaluate `main` and it will print following error:

```
<interactive>:1:1: error: Variable not in scope: main
```

You can see entire project at: [Haskell Editor Setup project](https://github.com/fairy-tale-agi-solutions/haskell-editor-setup/tree/faa16eef364d82a886b69d130c2cac9c84a5bbbe)

The `haskell-editor-setup.cabal` has `main-is: Main.hs` so I do not understand why it is not activated on `cabal repl` run.

I am also using `ide-haskell-repl` Atom extension which gives a REPL inside Atom and it works fine even though it is set to run by using `cabal repl`.

I am not sure whether this is a bug in `cabal` or something I am doing wrong. Any advice on how to fix this?

Running `:m *Main` or `:m +Main` in `cabal repl` will fix the issue but what I am looking for is to fix `cabal repl` run so that it loads Main properly.

Comment: I wonder if `:main` works?

Comment: @StevenFontanella No, `:main` does not work either, and it makes sense since `Main` module is not being loaded.

Comment: I guess it would help a lot if you could come up with a simpler reproducer. I am having a lot of trouble trying to build the project that you use as an example.

Comment: @kirelagin applying divide and conquer to get a minimal example would be more trouble than it is worth, I should focus on finishing the project. I can help you with any issues you might have in getting the project to build though, could you open an issue in the project github for the build problem you run into?